# In ruby with sinatra, How to get I response with get method on rest client?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rest-client, unauthorized, response-headers

I use ruby with sinatra and I used rest-client on import for payment.
I got token that string typed through post method on specific url: '... /users/getToken'.
Using this token, I wanna get payments information with get method on this url:

get_url = 'https://api/iamport.kr/payments/'+imp_uid

the detail codes are below,

```
def get_paymentsdetails(token, imp_uid)
    get_url = 'https://api.iamport.kr/payments/'+imp_uid

    response = RestClient.get get_url, :data => {}.to_json, :accept => :json, :headers => {'Authorization' => token}
    json = JSON.parse(response, :symbolize_names => true)
    # json = JSON.parse(response.to_json, {:symbolize_names => true})

    return json
end
```

However, I got 401 unauthorized error on this part of code.

```
response = RestClient.get get_url, :data => {}.to_json, :accept => :json, :headers => {'Authorization' => token}
```

After I access get_url with specific imp_uid, I got this page,{"code":-1,"message":"Unauthorized","response":null}

I checked parameter token and imp_uid of get_paymentsdetails function have valid string values,, so How can I access response parameter??
I think that there are some problems on response = RestClient.get get_url.... code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 'get' from the 'RestClient' class return some object with attributes. So response have few values. Which of them do you need? Access to them you can get by their names, its described [here](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client). 
In your case, after `response = RestClient.get get_url...` you should have variable `response` and ability to call `response.headers`, `response.code` or `response.body`.
But im afraid that you have some problems with autorization, which means that `imp_uid` or `token` is not correct. Thats why remote server sended to you responce with http-code 401 (Unauthorized). If it is so you should try to check your `imp_uid` and `token`. If everything is correct try to reach support of  iamport.kr .

Comment: Thanks, I success to get values of response,, 
but,, I got one more question, after I get some values and check that this value is valid,,,,,but I got html Text on redirect page,, I think this part may be response.body,, response.body is like this string code: "<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n ..."..
So, how can I get page that is parsed response body by HTML????

Comment: Before that, I change the code like this: response = RestClient.get get_url, {'Authorization' => token, :accept => json}, and I can use  some values of response on cotroller like that, @name = response[:response][:name], and I checked name has valid and correct value. I got last question above thing!!!! I want to parse that response.body to HTML,,,not string..

Comment: If i understood correctly your question, you can use [nokogiri gem](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) to parse html. You can pass `response.body` to nokogiri: `Nokogiri::HTML(response.body).at('body')`.

Comment: also take a look on [mechanize]{http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/}. Maybe it will fit better for your purposes